# How do i make custom date while its running realtime php

Tags: php

How can i make custom date while its running realtime with php

I want the date shown be 5.11.1900 (real time would be 5.11.2016)

```
echo "Today is " . date("d.m.Y") . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This, pass **Year** manually in date function or you pass **date** or manually in date functionlike this.

```
$year = "1990"; // add your year 
echo "Today is " . date("d.m.".$year) . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
echo "Today is " . date("d.m.1900") . "<br>";
```

Comment: thanks, this will solve the problem for this year, but would like to know how to make the year change also

Comment: you can use variable and replace it with 1900 Example $year = "2010";   date("d.m.$year")